# In atomic UX research, how do you document multiple instances of the same Fact?

Tags: ux-field, design-frameworks, ux-research

For context, I'm referring to [Daniel Pidcock's idea of Atomic Research](https://blog.prototypr.io/what-is-atomic-research-e5d9fbc1285c).

[image]

What happens if multiple users make the same comment? For example, if 5 users all say "I wish this button was easier to see", do you write that Fact down once, or do you write it 5 separate times? Part of me feels that it would be redundant to write it multiple times, but on the other hand, keeping each instance of the same comment as a separate atom is useful because it shows that multiple people said the same thing + preserves data about who said it, and in which Experiment.

I'm assuming the answer will depend on each person's company/projects/preferences, so I'm curious to know how you all deal with this type of situation.

Comment: How are the end data points being consumed? System, people, or both?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you look at the example that he uses to show Atomic Research in action:

[image]

The concept is really just to use your experiments to come up with the facts, and then use those facts to come up with insights.

So if you ran an experiment and 5 people said the same thing, this should be clear from your documentation, versus if you ran 5 experiments and 1 person from each experiment said the same thing. The fact is something objective that is not subject to interpretation, and the experiments are where the raw signals come from.

You don't want to base your insights on not knowing how the experiments and the facts were derived, because it can end up in misleading conclusions.